# Command line arguments in fortran (a filename, an integer, and another filename)

Tags: fortran

I am trying to read in arguments from the command line. I am able to successful read the three input arguments in, but they are stored as 1 string and I haven't been able to open the filename.

Goal: 
I want to be able to enter "./a.out input.dat frequency output.dat" 
and have the code actually accept all three input arguments and open and read in the data from the input.dat file.

Code:

```
program project 
implicit none

integer :: i
character(leng=32) :: arg

do i=1, iargc()
  call getarc(i,arg)
  write (*,*) arg
enddo

open (unit=1, file=arg, status = 'unknown')
read (unit=1, iostat=ios) stuff

end program project
```

Output (if I comment out the open/read lines)
input.dat 
frequency
output.dat

Now, I know there are probably other errors with the code (I just started), but I am mainly interested in knowing how I can improve the code to allow me to input a filename, open and read in the data from the file (mixed data types).

Thanks!

Comment: What is the output of your programs? Any error messages? Use status old, status unknown is useless.

Comment: This is a pretty broad question as written - it looks like you're interested in getting command line arguments, opening files, and reading data from a file with mixed types. Which of these are you having trouble with?

Comment: The problem is when I use "open." It is not opening and reading  the filename I entered. I can't put "file=input.dat" because I won't know the file name is entered when it is compiled. How to I access the first thing i entered? Like argv[1] in c. @Ross

Comment: With `getarc` you are reading the whole command. I suggest you to use the procedures in the answer linked by Ross or at least getargv to read the arguments separately.

Comment: First read each command line argument into a *separate* variable, then open with `file=inpf`.